# How can you put all relative URL to absolute URL using HTML DOM?

Tags: php, yii2, simple-html-dom

I need to replace all relative URL to absolute URL of a web page using only HTML DOM. It's possible?

I am also using yii2.

Example

Site:http://www.example.com

```
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="/page">Page</a>
```

Result:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="http://www.example.com/page">Page</a>
```

Comment: update you question adding the related  relevant code and the a sample for expected  result

Comment: add a `base` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set $scheme parameter to true to return an absolute url if you want to link to an controller action.

`Url::to(['my_controller/action'], true);`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail

For files you can use this `Html::a( $text, $url = null, $options = [] )` with below options

```
// A normal string. This will use the exact string as the href attribute
$url = 'images/logo.png'; // This returns href='images/logo.png'

// A string starting with a Yii2 alias
$url = '@web/images/logo.png' // This returns href='http://www.example.com/images/logo.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

you colud  use an url helper

assuming you have you css in  /yii2/web/css

```
<?php 
   use  yii\helpers\Url;
 echo '<link href="' .Url::base() . '/css/site.css' .'" rel="stylesheet">';
```

assuming you have you css in  /yii2/css

```
echo '<link href="' .Url::base() . '../css/site.css' .'" rel="stylesheet">';
```